# probability of a geometric distribution with independent variables

Tags: probability

If $X$ ~ Geo $(p)$  and $X_1, X_2$ are independent observations of $X$,

(a) calculate $P(X_1 + X_2 = 3)$,

(b) find $P(X_1 +X_2 =n)$,for $n \ge 2,$

---

(a) 
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
X_1 & X_2 \\
\hline
 1 & 2\\
2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$

$$P(X_1 + X_2 = 3)=2(p \cdot pq) = 2p^2q$$

(b) I don't know how to proceed for (b).

If I write $P(X_1 \ge 2) = pq^1 + pq^2 + \ldots = \frac{p}{1-q}$ Am I on the right track?
￼
Following an answer posted by a member in this community ,

\begin{align}
P(X_1+X_2=n) &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} P(X_1=i)P(X_2=n-i) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} q^{i-1}pq^{n-i-1}p \\
\end{align}

I proceeded as follows:

$\frac{p^2}{q^2} \sum ^n _{i=2} q^n$

This simplified to $p$ when the answer is $pq^{n-4}$

$\frac{p^2}{q^2} \sum ^n _{i=0} q^n - (1+q)$

$ \frac{p^2}{q^2} [\frac{1}{1-q} -(1+q)]$

Comment: Why not proceed exactly in the same way, that is, add $P(X_1=1,X_2=n-1)$, $P(X_1=2,X_2=n-2)$, ..., $P(X_1=n-1,X_2=1)$?

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Everything works and is correct up to "I proceeded as follows: $\frac{p^2}{q^2} \sum\limits^n _{i=2} q^n$" included. After this, I have no idea what you are doing, but anyway $\frac{p^2}{q^2} \sum\limits^n _{i=2} q^n=\frac{p^2}{q^2} (n-1)q^n=(n-1)p^2q^{n-2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(X_1+X_2=n) &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} P(X_1=i)P(X_2=n-i) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} q^{i-1}pq^{n-i-1}p \\
\end{align}

Can you collect the terms and simplify the equation?

Edit:

\begin{align}
P(X_1+X_2=n) &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} P(X_1=i)P(X_2=n-i) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} q^{i-1}pq^{n-i-1}p \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p^2q^{n-2} \\
&=(n-1)p^2q^{n-2}
\end{align}

Comment: I edited my answer above, could collect the terms, but it does not give the answer.

Comment: i edited my answer, note that $p^2q^{n-2}$ is independent of $i$.

Comment: It does follow a logic here. But still does not give the answer $pq^{n-4}$. Probably the answer given from my lecturer might be wrong too. I am accepting the answer. On further confirmation I will mark it as useful. Thnx

Comment: well, you already know the answer to $n=3$, you can verify if the lecturer's solution makes sense. =)